# First order PDE's. Determining when IVP solution is unique

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The initial value problem\begin{cases} 
      yu_x+xu_y=0 \\
       \\
      u(0,y)=e^{-{y^2}} 
   \end{cases}

has for solution $$u(x,y) = e^{x^2-y^2}$$

My question is, where in the $xy$-plane is the solution unique? The initial data asserts, that the solution must be a decreasing exponential on the characteristic curves. It somehow makes sense then, to claim that the region of interest is where $x^2 \leq y^2$.

How does one reach this conclusion rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDE implies that $u$ is constant, along the characteristics
$$
y^2-x^2=c, \quad c\in\mathbb R.
$$
In fact, every $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, with the exception of $(0,0)$ lies in a unique characteristic. The origin lies in $y=x$ and $y=-x$, where $u(0,0)=1$.

Nevertheless, only the characteristics with $c\ge 0$ intersect with the $y-$axis, where the initial data are prescribed.

Hence, the IVP enjoys uniqueness only in
$$
\{(x,y): |y|\ge |x|\}.
$$